# Why do I see a call to WaitForMultipleObjectsEx in this method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windbg, sos

I have a .NET windows form application that goes in a hang state once in a while. When I took a dump of the process and open it via WinDbg/SOS, it show that one thread has a call to `kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` although I am not calling any WaitXXX API on any event object in that particular method. That been said within I am doing check on InvokedRequired and IsDisposed APIs. Does any of call to InvokedRequired or IsDisposed  APIs internally call any WaitXXX API?

Here is the callstack for the thread.

```
[HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 0e4eedc0] System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle, UInt32, Boolean, Boolean)  
0e4eee6c 67b7689f System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int64, Boolean)  
0e4eee88 67b76855 System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32, Boolean)  
0e4eee9c 65c21a4f System.Windows.Forms.Control.WaitForWaitHandle(System.Threading.WaitHandle)  
0e4eeeb0 65f5d68b System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control, System.Delegate, System.Object[], Boolean)  
0e4eef50 65c233ac System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate, System.Object[])  
0e4eef84 65c2334f System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate)  
0e4eef88 6715ad76 MyNameSpace.MyClass.MyMethod()  
0e4eefb0 67b96e96 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)  
0e4eefbc 67ba031f System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)  
0e4eefd4 67b96e14 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()  
0e4ef1fc 68f81b4c [GCFrame: 0e4ef1fc]
```

Comment: Why don't you show us what your code was doing at the time?

Answer (score 1):

Many operations in Win32 (and thus .NET) will block. Because underneath all blocking APIs are really an asynchronous call with a wait, such wait calls are a common feature on stacks when the user thread is waiting for something from a kernel thread.

*Update (now I see your call stack)*: The wait is because the thread that calls `Invoke` needs to wait for the UI thread to complete the operation before returning. `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` is the underlying wait API for any user mode wait on a kernel handle (in this case probably an Event object).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of .Net methods that perform waits internally.

For example, `Control.Invoke` will wait on an event handle until the UI thread runs the callback.

Comment: What does it mean it applications hangs on this call to Invoke? Also any links/suggestions/design patterns on how to best call a Control.Invoke?

Comment: That would happen if you have a deadlock - if the UI thread is waiting for that thread to finish.  Use the debugger to look at call stacks and figure out what your code is doing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I already looked at !threads command and LockCount =0 for all managed threads. Also !syncBlk output has nothing either. Doesn't seem like its a deadlock. Because that's the only managed thread I see calling my code and is on a Wait state